# How can I put multiple check-boxes in one line with their labels?

Tags: sapui5

I want to design something like the following picture with smart fields:

[image]

When I try to design it with the following code:

```xml
<smartForm:GroupElement>
    <smartField:SmartField value="{Vermieter}"/>
    <smartField:SmartField value="{HIT}" textLabel="HIT"/>
    <smartField:SmartField value="{Konzessionär}" textLabel="Konzessionär"/>
</smartForm:GroupElement>
```

What I receive is the following result:

[image]

First of all the labels are missing.

And second the position is not perfectly correct. The distance between the second and the third items is not the same as we have between the first and the second items.

Any suggestion?

**Update**

Thanks to [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445898/how-can-i-put-multiple-check-boxes-in-one-line-with-their-labels?noredirect=1#comment112192645_63445898) of @MrNajzs I made the following progress:

```xml
<smartForm:GroupElement>
    <smartField:SmartLabel labelFor="Vermieter"/>
    <smartField:SmartField value="{Vermieter}" id="Vermieter"/>
    <smartField:SmartLabel labelFor="HIT"/>
    <smartField:SmartField value="{HIT}" id="HIT"/>
    <smartField:SmartLabel labelFor="Konzessionaer"/>
    <smartField:SmartField value="{Konzessionär}" id="Konzessionaer"/>
</smartForm:GroupElement>
```

but still there is a few problem. The elements are not adjusted still. Here is the output:

In view mode:
[image]

And in the edit mode:
[image]

Comment: Maybe [helpful](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12489267/how-to-place-2-textbox-in-one-line-with-label-alig.html).

Comment: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/ed/8fda66cd3b406cbd22f6019188ce82/content.htm?no_cache=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. I have to use for each element a different `Group` and use the `GridData` layout.

[image]

```xml
<smartForm:SmartForm flexEnabled="false">
    <smartForm:Group >
        <smartForm:GroupElement>
            <smartField:SmartField value="{RstID}" width="auto" contextEditable="true" >
                <smartField:configuration>
                    <smartField:Configuration preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false" displayBehaviour="descriptionOnly"/>
                </smartField:configuration>
            </smartField:SmartField>
        </smartForm:GroupElement>
    </smartForm:Group>
</smartForm:SmartForm>
<smartForm:SmartForm flexEnabled="false">
    <smartForm:layout>
        <smartForm:Layout labelSpanL="9" labelSpanM="9" labelSpanS="12" columnsL="3" columnsM="3" />
    </smartForm:layout>
    <smartForm:Group>
        <smartForm:layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="L4 M3 S6" indent="L1 M3"/>
        </smartForm:layoutData>
        <smartForm:GroupElement>
            <smartField:SmartField value="{Vermieter}"/>
        </smartForm:GroupElement>
    </smartForm:Group>
    <smartForm:Group>
        <smartForm:layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="L3 M3 S6"/>
        </smartForm:layoutData>
        <smartForm:GroupElement>
            <smartField:SmartField value="{HIT}"/>
        </smartForm:GroupElement>
    </smartForm:Group>
    <smartForm:Group>
        <smartForm:layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="L3 M3 S6"/>
        </smartForm:layoutData>
        <smartForm:GroupElement>
            <smartField:SmartField value="{Konzessionär}"/>
        </smartForm:GroupElement>
    </smartForm:Group>
</smartForm:SmartForm>
```

Still it is not a perfect solution as it can be seen there is a few different between the empty space of the first and second line, but still ignorable!

Answer (score 0):

You can "activate" the label by placing a `SmartLabel` before the `SmartField`.
In the `SmartLabel` you would need to reference the `SmartField` by its `Id` (as below)

```
<smartField:SmartLabel labelFor="idHIT" />
<smartField:SmartField id="idHIT" value="{HIT}" textLabel="HIT"/>
```

To control the layout you may want to explore the `smartField:layoutData` element.
Within this you can use a `GridData` element from the layout namespace.
But here there are many alternatives.

Comment: using `SmartLabel` will remove the `:` from the labels. It seems by using several `Group` it will produce better result. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.